Ipython для vscode при работе с логами
Как выяснилось расширение ipython для vscode не совсем корректно или не так как хотелось бы работает с логами. Вывод логов в консоль при перезапуске скрипта дублируется. Подробнее об этом тут. Возник следующий вопрос возможно ли каким то образом автоматизировать процесс удаления обработчиков перед запуском скрипта? Например с помощью файла settings.json или еще каким то образом.

а зачем вы плодите одинаковые вопросы?

Я так подумал, можно рассмотреть настройку логгера через .ini файл. Теоретически это так же должно сработать.

Мой следующий вопрос считают дублированием и удаляют, поэтому спрошу здесь. Есть ли  еще известные Вам конструкции в языке пайтон где при работе с ipython в vscode встретиться подобное неудобство?

@IvanIvanov как встретиться проблема, то тегните меня. Так сходу не могу сообразить на тему "подобных неудобств".
